# calculate the integral $\int_{\gamma}^{} \operatorname{Log}^2(z) \,dz$ where $\gamma$ is the given path:

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-integration, branch-cuts

Let $\gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ be a $C^1$ curve with $\gamma(0) = i, \gamma(1) = -i$ such that $\gamma$ does not intersect  $(-\infty,0] $.

Calculate the integral

$$ \int_{\gamma}^{} \operatorname{Log}^2(z) \,dz\ $$

I have applied the definition of integration of a complex valued function on a path as so:
$$ \int_{\gamma}^{} \operatorname{Log}^2(z) \,dz\  = \int_{0}^{1} \operatorname{Log}^2(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) \,dt\ $$

The question says to use the fundamental theorem of calculus but I can't find a primitive/antiderivative for this.

Comment: Integration by parts twice will get you an antiderivative

Comment: Have you tried $z=e^{(-\pi t+\frac\pi2)i}$?

Comment: @Andrei doesn't that curve intersect ($-\infty, 0]$? and that leads me to another issue which is that the integral shouldn't be the same for all paths right?

Comment: Yes, the integral is the same for all paths. The formula in my comment is the semicircle from $0+i$ to $1+0i$ (when $t=0.5$) to $0-i$.